# WebRequest throwing InvalidProgramException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, msbuild, .net-framework-version

I am using webrequest to fetch the data from remote server but suddenly the code stopped working and started throwing following error:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an
>   invalid program.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

I tried fixing this issue, I found that if I run the application in 32-bit mode it work fine but don't work for 64-bit. I have hosted the application on 64-bit OS.

However, it is working fine on my local machine.

I want to run my application in 64-bit mode to save more memory consumption issues.

Comment: What is your project's target platform?

Comment: Project's target platform is "Any CPU"

Answer (score 1):

- Ensure code optimization is not enabled in the project properties.
- On the server, ensure all Windows Update patches are installed, including the latest version of the .NET Framework.
- Update any NuGet packages to the latest available versions.
- Ensure that references on the server are resolving to the same assemblies that they are on your workstation. If a DLL reference is resolving to an older version, perhaps one built targeting .NET Framework 2, this could be the culprit.
- As a data-gathering step, try using the Debug configuration on the server. Some of [the reported Framework bugs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20%22Common%20Language%20Runtime%20detected%20an%20invalid%20program%22) producing this exception are specific to non-Debug configurations.
- Ensure the project targets the highest version of the .NET Framework possible.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the bounty and upvoted the answer by weir but don't have enough points left to comment. Anyway we wrote a test program to call GetResponse() directly and it crashes on the server. All of weir's points don't apply except updating Windows and in general any of the server code, so I would like to accept his answer in fairness so he gets the bounty, but don't know how. Posting the code below so that anybody can reproduce the issue more easily on their box if it happens to them.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Partial Class TestWebRequest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://en.wikipedia.org"), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Timeout = 30000
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim readStream As New StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)
            webRequestResponse.Text = "Result: " + readStream.ReadToEnd() + Environment.NewLine
            response.Close()
            readStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            webRequestResponse.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.ToString()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you not able to accept the answer ("click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in")?

Comment: I cannot accept the answer (maybe because I didn't post it) but I figured out that clicking on the bounty would award it to you. Thanks! On another note, we found that our test program works in CLR 2.0. So definitely some issue with the CLR 4.0 installed on that machine, whenever we can update it or reinstall I hope it will go away (waiting until we have an opportunity on that server). Edit: that 100 bounty is still clickable. I hope you got it.